# Installing perl-5.20.1 with Perlbrew. Failed tests in perl5db.t

Tags: perl, perlbrew

I am trying to install Perl v5.20.1 with Perlbrew, but it fails due to failed tests in a script `perl5db.t`. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with 64 bit architecture (x86_64).

Running:

```
$ perlbrew install perl-5.20.1
```

started installation fine and run for some minutes, but then aborted due to failed tests. Output:

```
Test Summary Report
-------------------
../lib/perl5db.t                                                (Wstat: 0 Tests: 119 Failed: 86)
  Failed tests:  19-56, 58-60, 63-64, 66, 68-72, 74, 76-80
                82-83, 85-101, 104-108, 110, 112, 114, 116-119
Files=2409, Tests=699745, 550 wallclock secs (34.45 usr  3.70 sys + 264.29 cusr 27.76 csys = 330.20 CPU)
Result: FAIL
```

From `~/perl5/perlbrew/build.perl-5.20.1.log` I can see that the first failed test is:

```
# Failed test 19 - Can set breakpoint in a line in the middle of the file. at ../lib/perl5db.t line 555
#      got 'In MyModule.
# In Main File.
# '
# expected /(?^msx:
#         ^Var=Bar$
#             .*
#         ^In\ MyModule\.$
#             .*
#         ^In\ Main\ File\.$
#             .*
#         )/
```

**Update**

I think I found more details about what causes the problem. I traced the problem by debugging the test script   `/home/hakon/perl5/perlbrew/build/perl-5.20.1/lib/perl5db.t` in the build directory.

The script `perl5db.t` is a script to test that the Perl debugger is working. The first failed test occurs when it tests if it can set a breakpoint on a line in the middle of a file. The file `/home/hakon/perl5/perlbrew/build/perl-5.20.1/lib/perl5db/t/filename-line-breakpoint` looks like:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use MyModule;

my $x = "Foo";

MyModule::function();

print "In Main File.\n";
```

and the included module `MyModule.pm` is:

```
package MyModule;

use strict;
use warnings;

use vars qw($var);

$var = "Bar";

sub function
{
    print "In MyModule.\n";
}

1;
```

The test script then runs Perl on the script using the `-d` switch and the following commands to the debugger:

```
b ../lib/perl5db/t/MyModule.pm:12
c
do { use IO::Handle; STDOUT->autoflush(1); print "Var=$var\n"; }
c
q
```

It expects the output from the debugger to be like (that is: matching) :

```
qr/
        ^Var=Bar$
            .*
        ^In\ MyModule\.$
            .*
        ^In\ Main\ File\.$
            .*
        /msx
```

But it gets:

```
In MyModule.
In Main File.
```

which does not match. So the problem is likely to be the

```
do { use IO::Handle; STDOUT->autoflush(1); print "Var=$var\n"; }
```

command, which does not produce any output at all..

Comment: Were other Perl versions installed successfully via Perlbrew?

Comment: @choroba This was the first one I tried. My system Perl is 5.18.2. Maybe I should try installing v5.18.4 with Perlbrew?

Comment: Does installing  with `install --notest` then `perlbrew switching` and reinstalling change anything?

Comment: Can you compile 5.20.1 from source and run tests?

Comment: @choroba I downloaded 5.20.1 from https://www.perl.org/get.html and run `./Configure -des -Dprefix=$HOME/localperl` and then `make test` it gave `Failed 1 test out of 2269, 99.96% okay. ` But the test that failed was the same as for the Perlbrew installation excpt that only the first of the 86 failed tests in `perl5db.t` for Perlbrew where reported. I guess it just skipped the rest of the tests in `perl5db.t` then?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was most likely due to a [bug](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=130445) in `perl5db.t` which expected the environment variable `PERLDB_OPTS` to be empty. But for my case it was not empty, but set to `NonStop` causing malfunction of the test script.