# How to reload Bash environment variables inside Perl script?

Tags: bash, perl

Is there a way to load Bash environment variables ( defined by sourcing `~/.bashrc` from a Bash shell ) from within a Perl script. Specifically, I am interested in reloading the `PERL5LIB` environment variable in the case the caller of the Perl script is not a child of a `bash` process<sup>1</sup>. In that case, `$ENV{PERL5LIB}` will not exist, which will prevent me from using any modules I have installed in my home directory.

A first attempt could be to rerun my myself under `bash` with the `-l` option. This will load `~/.bash_profile`, and I have set that file up to load `~/.bashrc`.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

if ( !exists $ENV{PERL5LIB} ) {    
    exec 'bash', '-lc', $0, @ARGV;
}
else {
    # Main program starts here..
}
```

But this could enter an infinite loop for the (unexpected) case that `PERL5LIB` is not defined in `~/.bashrc`.

**Footnotes:**

<sup>[1] This specific case occured for me when trying to write a native host to be called from the `google-chrome` process using the Google Chrome Extension API.</sup>

Comment: Sounds like your extension should install any nonstandard libraries along with the extension itself, and then you can hard-code the (relative) path and add it to `@INC` when you start up, rather than require the user to manage this (and any possible conflict between your libraries and those they actually want for their own needs).

Comment: If all you want to do is to load modules from your home directory, then why not do a `use lib` on your home directory instead of relying on the environment variable?

Comment: Your script doesn't even know if the caller *uses* `bash`; it's the *caller's* responsibility to make sure `PERL5LIB` has an appropriate value when calling the script.

Comment: @chepner For my use case the caller is `google-chrome`, and I agree that it is strange that it does not setup `PERL5LIB` for its child processes.

Comment: That said, `PERL5LIB` is probably something that should be defined *once* from `.bash_profile` and inherited, rather than setting every time an interactive shell is started. I don't know if `google-chrome` is being launched from a process that descends from an appropriate login shell in your case, though.

Comment: Re "*This specific case occured for me when trying to write a native host to be called from the google-chrome process using the Google Chrome Extension API.*", So? Your GUI has a login script too!

Comment: @ikegami I am not sure what you mean by GUI here. My script has no Graphical User Interface (GUI).

Comment: Chome's login "shell". Gnome? KDE?

Comment: @ikegami Ok, I see. So you are referring to `google-chrome` as *my GUI*. But still, I do not get it. What do you mean by *Your GUI has a login script*?

Comment: Re "*So you are referring to google-chrome as my GUI*", No, I'm not. I said I was talking about its login "shell", and I guessed that was either KDE or Gnome. /// Re "*What do you mean by «Your GUI has a login script?»*", A login script is a script that's executed when your login shell starts up (e.g. `.bash_profile` for `bash`). In this case, it's probably actually executed whenever the "shell" starts up (e.g. `.bashrc` for `bash`), so it might not technically be a *login* script, but it can still serve as one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

BEGIN {
    if (!exists( $ENV{PERL5LIB} )) {    
        if (!@ARGV || $ARGV[0] ne '--no-restart') {
            exec('bash', '-lc', '"$@"', $0, $^X, $0, '--no-restart', @ARGV);
        }
    }

    if (@ARGV && $ARGV[0] eq '--no-restart') {
        shift(@ARGV);
    }
}

...
```

(Obviously, using Getopt::Long or some-such would be better.)

This not only meets your spec, but provides a bypass if needed.

That said, the whole concept is flawed. Most people shouldn't be using PERL5LIB, and it's not your job to fix badly configured systems (those that need PERL5LIB but don't have it set when it should be set). Instead, [fix your environment](https://askubuntu.com/q/82120).

Comment: Thanks for the code. But I have some difficulty of getting my head around it. The arguments that is passed to `bash`: Why is `$0` passed twice? And what is `$@` doing?

Comment: The first argument after the script is put in `$0`, the next in `$1`, the next in `$2`, etc. `"$@"` is equivalent to `"$1" "$2" "$3" ...`. Notice we don't use `$0`, so we could pass any value for it. Compare `bash -c echo foo bar` with `bash -c '"$@"' dummy echo foo bar`

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense to me now. But why shouldn't we use `PERL5LIB`? I have always been using it. First I install `cpan App::cpanminus`; at this initial install `cpan` will ask if I will install in my home directory or in the system directory ( requires root privileges ). I always choose to install in my home directory. Then, I need to set PERL5LIB.

Comment: Re "*But why shouldn't we use PERL5LIB?*", There's no reason to. If you're using the system Perl, you should be using the system's package manager. If you're using your own Perl, then why would you need it.

Comment: I use the system Perl, but as I said, I installed packages in my home directory. Then I do not need root privileges to install packages. What do you mean by *the system's package manager*? Are you referring to something other than `cpan` or `cpanm` here?

Comment: @HåkonHægland e.g. yum, aptitude. What OS/distro are you running?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot But only a small percentage of the Perl modules are available as Ubuntu packages. So why bother with `sudo apt-get install` then? Isn't it simpler to just use `cpanm`?

Comment: You can override your distro if you want, but that can lead to problems, so I don't believe it's something people should do. (Example problem: A module you install with `cpan` directly or as a dependency does exist in a system package, and you install a program using your distro's package manager using that uses that module. That program will pick up your version instead of the distro's version it was tested with.)

Comment: There's also the issue that most people using `PERL5LIB` populate it using `install::lib` and thus via the problematic `INSTALL_BASE`. This isn't a problem with `PERL5LIB` itself, though.

Comment: Ok, I see. There are many quirks here :). Thanks for your time. I accept this now as it seems to be the best approach for my problem.

Comment: No, it isn't. Not even close. The best approach would be to set PERL5LIB in your login shell (KDE, Gnome, bash, whatever)

Comment: @HåkonHægland To add to ikegami's examples, here's one I've actually encountered at $work: upgraded a module that was originally installed with yum to the latest version using cpan; yum updates months later downgraded the module, and it was a big pain to track down. If you must use the system perl and can't find a suitable package, there are [tools](https://debian-administration.org/article/78/Building_Debian_packages_of_Perl_modules) to create packages from the module source. But usually it's easier to just install your own copy of perl in your home directory using perlbrew or plenv.

Comment: In fact, if you've configured `cpanm` to do so, you've also configured `cpan` to do so.

Comment: @ikegami I have already set `PERL5LIB` in my bash login shell, since `~/.bash_profile` sources `~/.bashrc`. I am not sure what more I could do here?

Comment: @Håkon Hægland, Re "*I am not sure what more I could do here?*". That's not the program you execute on login, or else that would be sufficient. (I suppose something else might be changing your environment.) I have no idea what you execute on login. Is it KDE? Gnome? Something else?

Comment: @ikegami I am using Unity as the default desktop environment for Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot *"But usually it's easier to just install your own copy of perl in your home directory using perlbrew or plenv"* Or you could try install all your Perl modules using `cpan` and `cpanm`? If I never use my distros package manager to install Perl packages I should be rather safe? At least, I have never experienced any problems with this during the 3 years I have programmed in Perl. I have also tried using `perlbrew` but that was not so successful :)

Comment: @HåkonHægland Your distro already comes with a number of modules installed, so it's not possible to only use cpan. You won't see issues often, but they do happen; there's no reason to risk such needless problems because it's incredibly easy to install additional copies of perl. You should post another question about your perlbrew issues.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Yeah. I guess you are right! I was discouraged by some initial attempts, see for example [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28433032/installing-perl-5-20-1-with-perlbrew-failed-tests-in-perl5db-t), so I abandoned the idea and used `cpanm` with my system perl instead.

Comment: Re "*Your distro already comes with a number of modules installed*", Not only that, you might install some program that uses Perl and Perl modules.

Comment: Re "*I am using Unity*", Then I mean Unity. There's gotta be some way of settings env vars for Unity. A quick google later: [Solution?](http://askubuntu.com/q/82120). Link added to answer.

Answer (score 6):

[`Env::Modify`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Env::Modify) can modify your environment from shell scripts.

Something like

```
use Env::Modify 'source';

# BEGIN { ???
if (!exists($ENV{PERL5LIB})) {
    source("$ENV{HOME}/.bashrc");
    die "PERL5LIB not in .bashrc" unless $ENV{PERL5LIB};
    exec($^X, $0, @ARGV);     # restart
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem now is that `Env::Modify` is also installed in my home directory ( I am using `cpanm` ).